# raise BadSyntax(self._thisDoc, self.lines, argstr, i, msg) rdflib.plugins.parsers.notation3.BadSyntax:

Tags: python, parsing, sparql, rdflib

I tried to parse a file in turtle format but I am getting this error and cannot find how to solve it :

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/gpfs7kw/linkhome/rech/genlig01//test/expe_5/dbnary_corpus/extract.py", line 25, in <module>
    result = g.parse('fr_dbnary_ontolex.ttl', format='n3')
  File "/linkhome/rech/genlig01//.conda/envs/bert/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rdflib/graph.py", line 1078, in parse
    parser.parse(source, self, **args)
  File "/linkhome/rech/genlig01//.conda/envs/bert/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rdflib/plugins/parsers/notation3.py", line 1915, in parse
    TurtleParser.parse(self, source, conj_graph, encoding, turtle=False)
  File "/linkhome/rech/genlig01/u/.conda/envs/bert/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rdflib/plugins/parsers/notation3.py", line 1886, in parse
    p.loadStream(source.getByteStream())
  File "/linkhome/rech/genlig01/u/.conda/envs/bert/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rdflib/plugins/parsers/notation3.py", line 442, in loadStream
    return self.loadBuf(stream.read())    # Not ideal
  File "/linkhome/rech/genlig01/umg16uw/.conda/envs/bert/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rdflib/plugins/parsers/notation3.py", line 448, in loadBuf
    self.feed(buf)
  File "/linkhome/rech/genlig01//.conda/envs/bert/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rdflib/plugins/parsers/notation3.py", line 474, in feed
    i = self.directiveOrStatement(s, j)
  File "/linkhome/rech/genlig01//.conda/envs/bert/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rdflib/plugins/parsers/notation3.py", line 495, in directiveOrStatement
    j = self.statement(argstr, i)
  File "/linkhome/rech/genlig01//.conda/envs/bert/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rdflib/plugins/parsers/notation3.py", line 733, in statement
    j = self.property_list(argstr, i, r[0])
  File "/linkhome/rech/genlig01//.conda/envs/bert/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rdflib/plugins/parsers/notation3.py", line 1096, in property_list
    self.BadSyntax(argstr, j,
  File "/linkhome/rech/genlig01//.conda/envs/bert/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rdflib/plugins/parsers/notation3.py", line 1623, in BadSyntax
    raise BadSyntax(self._thisDoc, self.lines, argstr, i, msg)
rdflib.plugins.parsers.notation3.BadSyntax: at line 2093929 of <>:
Bad syntax (objectList expected) at ^ in:
"...b'rotecteur."@fr ] .\n\n<http://kaiko.getalp.org/dbnary/fra/__tr'^b'_eng_1_facteur_d\xe2\x80\x99att\xc3\xa9nuation__nom__1>\n        rdf:type   '..."
```

I made a search in the file but the line is correctly written. So I do not how to dit, I have to parse the file.

here code :

```
# read specific columns of csv file using Pandas

import csv
import os
import pprint

import rdflib
from rdflib import Graph, Literal, RDF, URIRef
# rdflib knows about quite a few popular namespaces, like W3C ontologies, schema.org etc.
from rdflib.namespace import FOAF , XSD

g = rdflib.Graph()

result = g.parse('fr_dbnary_ontolex.ttl', format='n3') # 

q_noun = """
    
SELECT * WHERE {
       ?lexeme a ontolex:LexicalEntry ;
         rdfs:label ?label ;
         lexinfo:partOfSpeech lexinfo:noun;
         dbnary:synonym   ?syn .
    }
"""

for p, o, s in g.query(q_noun):
      with open("dbnary_synonym.tsv", 'a', encoding='utf-8') as f:
          f.write(p + "\t" + o + "\t" + s + '\n')
```

I changed the format to turtle but the erro is still produced.

this how the file look like just the beguinning because the file is quite huge

```
@prefix dbetym:   <http://etytree-virtuoso.wmflabs.org/dbnaryetymology#> .
@prefix dbnary:   <http://kaiko.getalp.org/dbnary#> .
@prefix dbstats:  <http://kaiko.getalp.org/dbnary/statistics/> .
@prefix dcterms:  <http://purl.org/dc/terms/> .
@prefix decomp:   <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .
@prefix fra:      <http://kaiko.getalp.org/dbnary/fra/> .
@prefix lexinfo:  <http://www.lexinfo.net/ontology/2.0/lexinfo#> .
@prefix lexvo:    <http://lexvo.org/id/iso639-3/> .
@prefix lime:     <http://www.w3.org/ns/lemon/lime#> .
@prefix olia:     <http://purl.org/olia/olia.owl#> .
@prefix ontolex:  <http://www.w3.org/ns/lemon/ontolex#> .
@prefix qb:       <http://purl.org/linked-data/cube#> .
@prefix rdf:      <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix rdfs:     <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@prefix skos:     <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#> .
@prefix synsem:   <http://www.w3.org/ns/lemon/synsem#> .
@prefix vartrans: <http://www.w3.org/ns/lemon/vartrans#> .
@prefix wikt:     <https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/> .
@prefix xs:       <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .
fra:accueil__nom__1  rdf:type  ontolex:Word , ontolex:LexicalEntry ;
        rdfs:label             "accueil"@fr ;
        dbnary:partOfSpeech    "-nom-" ;
        dbnary:synonym         fra:home , fra:main_page , <http://kaiko.getalp.org/dbnary/fra/page_d’accueil> ;
        dcterms:language       lexvo:fra ;
        lexinfo:partOfSpeech   lexinfo:noun ;
        lime:language          "fr" ;
        ontolex:canonicalForm  fra:__cf_accueil__nom__1 ;
        ontolex:sense          fra:__ws_1_accueil__nom__1 , fra:__ws_2_accueil__nom__1 , fra:__ws_3_accueil__nom__1 , fra:__ws_4_accueil__nom__1 , fra:__ws_5_accueil__nom__1 .
fra:__cf_accueil__nom__1
        rdf:type             ontolex:Form ;
        lexinfo:gender       lexinfo:masculine ;
        ontolex:phoneticRep  "a.kœj"@fr-fonipa ;
        ontolex:writtenRep   "accueil"@fr .
fra:lire__verb__1  rdf:type    ontolex:Word , ontolex:LexicalEntry ;
        rdfs:label             "lire"@fr ;
        dbnary:partOfSpeech    "-verb-" ;
        dbnary:synonym         fra:lire ;
        dcterms:language       lexvo:fra ;
        lexinfo:partOfSpeech   lexinfo:verb ;
        lime:language          "fr" ;
        ontolex:canonicalForm  fra:__cf_lire__verb__1 ;
        ontolex:sense          fra:__ws_1_lire__verb__1 , fra:__ws_2_lire__verb__1 , fra:__ws_3_lire__verb__1 , fra:__ws_4_lire__verb__1 , fra:__ws_5_lire__verb__1 , fra:__ws_6_lire__verb__1 , fra:__ws_7_lire__verb__1 , fra:__ws_8_lire__verb__1 , fra:__ws_9_lire__verb__1 .      
fra:meuble__adj__1  rdf:type   ontolex:Word , ontolex:LexicalEntry ;
        rdfs:label             "meuble"@fr ;
        dbnary:antonym         fra:dur , fra:solide , fra:immeuble ;
        dbnary:partOfSpeech    "-adj-" ;
        dcterms:language       lexvo:fra ;
        lexinfo:partOfSpeech   lexinfo:adjective ;
        lime:language          "fr" ;
        ontolex:canonicalForm  fra:__cf_meuble__adj__1 ;
        ontolex:sense          fra:__ws_1_meuble__adj__1 , fra:__ws_2_meuble__adj__1 .
fra:militaire__adj__1
        rdf:type               ontolex:Word , ontolex:LexicalEntry ;
        rdfs:label             "militaire"@fr ;
        dbnary:antonym         fra:civil ;
        dbnary:partOfSpeech    "-adj-" ;
        dbnary:synonym         fra:martial , fra:guerrier ;
        dcterms:language       lexvo:fra ;
        lexinfo:partOfSpeech   lexinfo:adjective ;
        lime:language          "fr" ;
        ontolex:canonicalForm  fra:__cf_militaire__adj__1 ;
        ontolex:sense          fra:__ws_1_militaire__adj__1 , fra:__ws_2_militaire__adj__1 , fra:__ws_3_militaire__adj__1 .

fra:mercredi__adv__1  rdf:type  ontolex:Word , ontolex:LexicalEntry ;
        rdfs:label             "mercredi"@fr ;
        dbnary:partOfSpeech    "-adv-" ;
        dbnary:synonym         fra:civil1 ;
        dcterms:language       lexvo:fra ;
        lexinfo:partOfSpeech   lexinfo:adverb ;
        lime:language          "fr" ;
        ontolex:canonicalForm  fra:__cf_mercredi__adv__1 ;
        ontolex:sense          fra:__ws_1_mercredi__adv__1 .

fra:mercredi__adv__1  rdf:type  ontolex:Word , ontolex:LexicalEntry ;
        rdfs:label             "mercredi"@fr ;
        dbnary:synonym         fra:civil2 ;
        dbnary:partOfSpeech    "-adv-" ;
        dcterms:language       lexvo:fra ;
        lexinfo:partOfSpeech   lexinfo:adverb ;
        lime:language          "fr" ;
        ontolex:canonicalForm  fra:__cf_mercredi__adv__1 ;
        ontolex:sense          fra:__ws_1_mercredi__adv__1 .

<http://kaiko.getalp.org/dbnary/fra/page_d’accueil>
        rdf:type          dbnary:Page ;
        dbnary:describes  <http://kaiko.getalp.org/dbnary/fra/page_d’accueil__nom__1> .

<http://kaiko.getalp.org/dbnary/fra/page_d’accueil>
        rdf:type          dbnary:Page ;
        dbnary:describes  <http://kaiko.getalp.org/dbnary/fra/page_d’accueil__nom__1> .
```

Comment: can you share the file or at least some self-contained subset of the data with the erroneous line?

Comment: @UninformedUser I added a snippet of the file.

Comment: Check around line 2093929. The error message seems to have things in it, "__tr" and "facteur", that do not appear in the data shown.

Comment: Yes, you need to check lines 2093929 as AndyS says since the snippet you posted parses just fine.

Comment: @kely789456123 did you able to solve the issue? I am getting the same error